# Flink + Kafka + JSON - java example

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I'm trying to get a JSON from a Kafka topic with this code:

```java
public class FlinkMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        // parse user parameters
        ParameterTool parameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);

        DataStream messageStream = env.addSource(
                new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<>(parameterTool.getRequired("topic")
                , new JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema(false), parameterTool.getProperties()));

        messageStream.map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -6867736771747690202L;

            @Override
            public String map(String value) throws Exception {
                return "Kafka and Flink says: " + value;
            }
        });

        env.execute();
    }
}
```

The issues are:

1) this program does not run due

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.InvalidTypesException: The return type of function 'main(FlinkMain.java:23)' could not be determined automatically, due to type erasure. You can give type information hints by using the returns(...) method on the result of the transformation call, or by letting your function implement the 'ResultTypeQueryable' interface.

The problem is at line: `messageStream.map(....`
```

2) Maybe the above issue is related to the fact that `DataStream` has no type. But if I try to make:

`DataStream<String> messageStream = env.addSource(...`

The code will not compile due `cannot resolve constructor FlinkKafkaConsumer09 ...`

The `pom.xml` (the important part):

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I've been looking for some code in Flink that uses a JSON DeserializationSchema without success. I've just found the unit test for the `JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema` at this [link](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-connectors/flink-connector-kafka-base/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchemaTest.java)

Does anyone knows how to do the right way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is at the line `messageStream.map(new MapFunction<String, String>()`. The mapFunction you defined expects an Input of the type String and output of the type String, but since you are using a `JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema` which converts String to `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode` your MapFunction should actually expect an input of the same type ObjectNode. Try the below code.

```
messageStream.map(new MapFunction<ObjectNode, String>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -6867736771747690202L;

        @Override
        public String map(ObjectNode node) throws Exception {
            return "Kafka and Flink says: " + node.get(0);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

I followed **Vishnu viswanath** answer, however **JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema** raises an exception during JSON parser step, even for a simple JSON as `{"name":"John Doe"}`.

The code that throws is:

```
DataStream<ObjectNode> messageStream = env.addSource(
    new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<>(parameterTool.getRequired("topic")
    , new JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema(false), parameterTool.getProperties()));

messageStream.rebalance().map(new MapFunction<ObjectNode, String>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6867736771747690202L;

    @Override
    public String map(ObjectNode node) throws Exception {
        return "Kafka and Flink says: " + node.get(0);
    }
}).print();
```

Output:

```
09/05/2016 11:16:02 Job execution switched to status FAILED.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:822)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(JobManager.scala:768)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(JobManager.scala:768)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:401)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:790)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2215)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema.deserialize(JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema.java:52)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema.deserialize(JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema.java:38)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Kafka09Fetcher.run(Kafka09Fetcher.java:227)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I was succeeded using another deserialization schema **JSONDeserializationSchema**

```
        DataStream<ObjectNode> messageStream = env.addSource(
            new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<>(parameterTool.getRequired("topic")
                    , new JSONDeserializationSchema(), parameterTool.getProperties()));

    messageStream.rebalance().map(new MapFunction<ObjectNode, String>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -6867736771747690202L;

        @Override
        public String map(ObjectNode value) throws Exception {
            return "Kafka and Flink says: " + value.get("key").asText();
        }
    }).print();
```